# Calabash test android with React-native

Tags: android, react-native, calabash, calabash-android

i'm working with Calabash-Ui-Test, i'm using react-native for android,
i want to write a scenario using the ID to target my view, so i add `testID` for my components.
So in my scenario i used:
`Given I wait for the view with id "NoResourceEntry-47" to appear`
and When i added `testID` props to my my components, i want to write something like this:
`Given I wait for the view with id "My-testID" to appear`

But it does not work, when i run the query function: `query('*')` i found that the `testID` is replaced by `tag` in the result like:

```
        "id" => "NoResourceEntry-47",
               "enabled" => true,
    "contentDescription" => nil,
               "visible" => true,
                   **"tag" => "overview_Button",**
```

Any solution to use tag or replace tag with id ?

Thank you